# Как достать ид из пересланного сообщения

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем привет! Пишу бота и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне надо из сообщения на который ответили (переслали) узнать ID человека.

Можно пожалуйста ответ кодом (я новичок в vk api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сообщения-ответа в объекте сообщения есть свойство `reply_message` - это объект сообщения, на которое ответили.
Для сообщения с пересланными сообщениями в объекте сообщения есть свойство 'fwd_messages' - это массив объектов пересланных сообщений.
ID автора доступен через свойство `from_id` нужного объекта сообщения.

P.S: event.obj.message['reply_message']['from_id']